# What is the regex pattern for extracting the substring to the left of four numbers attached to an uppercase word?

Tags: r, regex

I have a string `ARC GUNNA SPARKYA  2011QUARTER HORSE.`

I'd like to extract only the ARC GUNNA SPARKYA part. I.e., everything to the left of the "2011QUARTER."

I will also have valid strings which I want the pattern NOT to match. Valid strings would be "10RUNS FAST" or "QUICKER 1".

Note that the above means I need a pattern which can explicitly pick up just any four numbers followed by the uppercase word "QUARTER."

I tried `([0-9A-Za-z]+( [0-9A-Za-z]+)+)` but that pattern matches the part I want to keep too, so I can't use it to do something like `gsub`.

Can you please help me understand what regex pattern will accomplish this--particularly in R?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sub` with a capture group, and use that group in the replacement.

```
(.*?)\s+\d{4}QUARTER\b.*
```

**Explanation**

- `(.*?)` Capture group 1, match any character, as few as possible
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace characters
- `\d{4}QUARTER\b` Match 4 digits followed by the word QUARTER
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jDC9Nm/1).

```
text <- "ARC GUNNA SPARKYA 2011QUARTER HORSE"
result = sub("(.*?)\\s+\\d{4}QUARTER\\b.*", "\\1", text)
result
```

Output

```
[1] "ARC GUNNA SPARKYA"
```